# Configuring settings for all rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am aware that in rails you have three environments: production, test and development. In each of the separate file one could specify a set of config that will apply to the environment. I was wondering whether it was possible to have a config that is applicable to a 3 environments, if it is yes, which file would that be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be `config/environment.rb` (or `config/application.rb` in newer versions of Rails). There are other places to put application-wide configuration settings; for more details there [is a good Guide on the topic.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)